# React and nginx: refused to connect to localhost

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have my React (frontend) and Django REST (backend) running on a remote Ubuntu server with nginx. I also have a simple reverse proxy defined in `conf.d/bookmarks.conf` to manage all of that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /api/ {    # Backend
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/;

    }

    location / {    # Frontend
        root        /var/www/bookmarks/html/;
        index       index.html;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    } 
}
```

I run my Django app with `runserver python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:1337`, and React static files are stored in the folder described above

I try to connect to API with React:

```
const generateOpendIdLink = async () => {
      const generateOpendIdLinkEndpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/opendid-link-generator/';
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      };

      try {
        const response = await fetch(generateOpendIdLinkEndpoint, requestOptions);
        if (response.status == 200) {
          ...
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      };
    };
```

And get an error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/api/opendid-link-generator/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is quite odd, because I could connect to API from the web no problem: running the same GET on the server IP address `http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/api/opendid-link-generator/` from Postman works as expected. This is also true when I change 127.0.0.1 for the server IP in the React code, it all starts to work.

I also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` for test purposes while trying to solve this problem, and it did not help. Does anyone know what could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about javascript, but let me give it a shot:

```js
const generateOpendIdLinkEndpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1/api/opendid-link-generator/';
```

This definition does not include the port! Most likely it looks up the default http port at `:80` then. Try to include the port and let me know!

Comment: I tried it, and it did not work, sadly. As far as I know, reverse proxy would direct default `:80` to the one specified in the `.conf` file, e.g. 1337 for the `/api`.

Answer (score 0):

The JS code is executed on the client device and will therefore not share `localhost` with the Django app. That's why you need to specify the IP-address to the server.